# Use specific DataTemplate for unknown columns

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, datagrid

I have a DataGrid with the ItemsSource bound to a DataTable that I populate in the code behind. The DataTable has a dynamic number of columns but the first 2 are always the same plain text columns. What I want is that the all but the first 2 columns use a DataTemplate that I've defined

```
<DataGrid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" DataContext="{Binding myDataTable}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
```

Here's the template

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="myCellTemplate">
    <StackPanel>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsAssigned}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Quantity}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

And the DataTable gets created in my ViewModel, the number of columns is defined at runtime:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name"));
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID"));
int colCount = 2;
foreach (Item i in this.Items)
{
    if (item.Condition)
    {
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(item.Name.ToString()));
        colCount++;
    }
}
```

How do I approach assigning `myCellTemplate` to the cells in the `Item` columns?

Comment: I think you can use the DataGrid's [AutoGeneratingColumn event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratingcolumn.aspx) to affect what template each column uses.

Comment: @Rachel thanks that approach seems promising, one issue though I'm not sure what's the data context inside myCellTemplate. When I change the template the cells are blank so I'm guessing my Binding paths are off

Comment: Your column contains a single `string` value, while your cell template is trying to bind to the `IsAssigned` and `Quantity` properties of string, which of course does not exist. My recommendation would be to get rid of the `DataTable` entirely, and create a custom class to correctly represent your items. In this case, it sounds like you might need two classes : ClassA with Id, Name, and a collection of ClassB, and ClassB with properties for Value, IsAssigned, and Quantity. Parse the data into your custom class objects, and bind your DataGrid to an `ObservableCollection<ClassA>` of your objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this in the past in two ways. Here's my best guess at the syntax, although it hasn't really been tested at all.

1. Use the [AutoGeneratingColumn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratingcolumn.aspx) event to set properties (like Template) based on column-specific values, such as Header or DisplayIndex.

   ```
   private void MyDataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
   {
       string headerName = e.Column.Header.ToString();
       int columnIndex = e.Column.DisplayIndex;

       // change some property of e.Column based on headerName or columnIndex
   }
   ```
2. Use a DataTrigger in the DataGridCell Style. You can set your trigger on either `Column.DisplayIndex` or `Column.Header`.

   ```
   <DataGrid.Resources>
       <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
           <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource myCellTemplate}" />
           <Style.Triggers>
               <DataTrigger Value="0" Binding="{Binding Path=Column.DisplayIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                   <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource defaultTemplate}" />
               </DataTrigger>
               <DataTrigger Value="1" Binding="{Binding Path=Column.DisplayIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                   <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource defaultTemplate}" />
               </DataTrigger>
           </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
   </DataGrid.Resources>
   ```

   You'll need a default template defined for your first two columns to use this XAML, unless you want to create a Converter to figure out if `DisplayIndex > 1` or `ColumnName != ID or Name`